# Как дать пользователю вставлять картинку на сайте?

Tags: html, css, изображения

Я хочу сделать страницу профиля, что бы пользователь мог загрузить своё фото на аватар, подскажите, как это сделать? В сети(скорее всего я криворукий, и плохо искал) ответа я не нашел.

Comment: Вы в документацию заглядываете хоть иногда? http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/20811/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0

Comment: вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/205744/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80

Answer (score 1):

1. Делаем загрузчик (`<input name="myFile" type="file">`)
2. На стороне сервера проверяем что это такое нам прислали - должна быть картинка
3. Сохраняем ее на сервер, ее адрес сохраняем в базу
4. При генерации любого элемента, в котором есть профиль пользователя подтягиваем нужную картинку и вставляем туда

Это в кратце :)

Comment: подскажите, а где можно по подробнее почитать?

Comment: Сначала прочитайте про input type=file. Потом смотрим как на сервер получаем файл. Потом посмотрите как на клиенте и сервере валидировать полученный файл. Потом смотрим как сохранять файлы на сервере. Потом посмотрите как писать и читать в базу данных. Ну а потом я думаю уже будет все понятно :) Все это в гугле конечно же можно найти.

Comment: Нет, тут нужно сначала про http протокол почитать, а не соц.сеть делать сразу

Comment: Мне кажется, что сначала надо что-бы человек что-то сделал, у него получилось, он увлекся, а потом он уже и сам начнет копать и прот протоколы и про другие "страшные" вещи :)